# Optimize parsing file with JSON objects in pandas dataframe, where keys may be missing in some rows

Tags: python, json, performance, pandas, memory

I'm looking to optimize the code below which takes ~5 seconds, which is too slow for a file of only 1000 lines.

I have a large file where each line contains valid JSON, with each JSON looking like the following (the actual data is much larger and nested, so I use this JSON snippet for illustration):

```
  {"location":{"town":"Rome","groupe":"Advanced",
    "school":{"SchoolGroupe":"TrowMet", "SchoolName":"VeronM"}},
    "id":"145",
    "Mother":{"MotherName":"Helen","MotherAge":"46"},"NGlobalNote":2,
    "Father":{"FatherName":"Peter","FatherAge":"51"},
    "Teacher":["MrCrock","MrDaniel"],"Field":"Marketing",
     "season":["summer","spring"]}
```

I need to parse this file in order to extract only some key-values from every JSON, to obtain the resulting dataframe:

```
Groupe      Id   MotherName   FatherName
Advanced    56   Laure         James
Middle      11   Ann           Nicolas
Advanced    6    Helen         Franc
```

But some keys I need in the dataframe, are missing in some JSON objects, so I should to verify if the key is present, and if not, fill the corresponding value with Null. I use with the following method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['group', 'id', 'Father', 'Mother'])
with open (path/to/file) as f:
    for chunk in f:
        jfile = json.loads(chunk)

        if 'groupe' in jfile['location']:
            groupe = jfile['location']['groupe']
        else:
            groupe=np.nan

        if 'id' in jfile:
            id = jfile['id']
        else:
            id = np.nan

        if 'MotherName' in jfile['Mother']:
            MotherName = jfile['Mother']['MotherName']
        else:
            MotherName = np.nan

        if 'FatherName' in jfile['Father']:
            FatherName = jfile['Father']['FatherName']
        else: 
            FatherName = np.nan

        df = df.append({"groupe":group, "id":id, "MotherName":MotherName, "FatherName":FatherName},
            ignore_index=True)
```

I need to optimize the runtime over the whole 1000-row file to <= 2 seconds. In PERL the same parsing function takes < 1 second, but I need to implement it in Python.

Comment: You should use Python's [`dict.get(key, default)` method which optionally takes a `default` value for when `key` is not found](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get). That also makes your inner-loop code 4x more compact and legible. But you could probably use `dict.update` or `defaultdict` to reduce even further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the best performance if you can build the dataframe in a single step during initialization. `DataFrame.from_record` takes a sequence of tuples which you can supply from a generator that reads one record at a time. You can parse the data faster with `get`, which will supply a default parameter when the item isn't found. I created an empty `dict` called `dummy` to pass for intermediate `get`s so that you know a chained get will work.

I created a 1000 record dataset and on my crappy laptop the time went from 18 seconds to .06 seconds. Thats pretty good.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import time

def extract_data(data):
    """ convert 1 json dict to records for import"""
    dummy = {}
    jfile = json.loads(data.strip())
    return (
        jfile.get('location', dummy).get('groupe', np.nan), 
        jfile.get('id', np.nan),
        jfile.get('Mother', dummy).get('MotherName', np.nan),
        jfile.get('Father', dummy).get('FatherName', np.nan))

start = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(map(extract_data, open('file.json')),
    columns=['group', 'id', 'Father', 'Mother'])
print('New algorithm', time.time()-start)

#
# The original way
#

start= time.time()
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['group', 'id', 'Father', 'Mother'])
with open ('file.json') as f:
      for chunk in f:
           jfile=json.loads(chunk)
           if 'groupe' in jfile['location']:
               groupe=jfile['location']['groupe']
           else:
               groupe=np.nan
           if 'id' in jfile:
                id=jfile['id']
           else:
                id=np.nan
           if 'MotherName' in jfile['Mother']:
                MotherName=jfile['Mother']['MotherName']
           else:
                MotherName=np.nan
           if 'FatherName' in jfile['Father']:
                FatherName=jfile['Father']['FatherName']
           else: 
                FatherName=np.nan
           df = df.append({"groupe":groupe,"id":id,"MotherName":MotherName,"FatherName":FatherName},
            ignore_index=True)
print('original', time.time()-start)
```

Comment: I have `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'` with this method! Don't forget that I have a file with json oon each line, maybe this is a problem. So I need iterate over the lines to parse each json

Comment: so the whole file is not json itself, but every line of this file is a valid json

Comment: it works except of the case when instead of dictionary there is a nested json! how to use .get method in this case? @tdelaney

Comment: I'm not sure what "nested json" means. Is it a single json-encoded string? Perhaps you could decode it and replace the string with the decoded structure.

Comment: Amanda please edit your question to add example data for those corner-cases. Parsing issues in JSON are a real pain to reproduce... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The key part is not to append each row to the dataframe in the loop.  You want to keep the collection in a list or dict container and then concatenate all of them at once.  You can also simplify your `if/else` structure with a simple `get` that returns a default value (e.g. np.nan) if the item is not found in the dictionary.

```
with open (path/to/file) as f:
    d = {'group': [], 'id': [], 'Father': [], 'Mother': []}
    for chunk in f:
        jfile = json.loads(chunk)
        d['groupe'].append(jfile['location'].get('groupe', np.nan))
        d['id'].append(jfile.get('id', np.nan))
        d['MotherName'].append(jfile['Mother'].get('MotherName', np.nan))
        d['FatherName'].append(jfile['Father'].get('FatherName', np.nan))

    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Your answer is good n but there is an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` while converting dictionary into pandas dataframe

Comment: Sounds like there might be a problem with the data. Try to make a DataFrame from each column and see if you can isolate the issue.