# .get method for nested json doesn't work

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a large file, that contains **valid nested json** on each line, each json looks like (real data is much bigger, so this peace of json will be shown for illustration just):

```
       {"location":{"town":"Rome","groupe":"Advanced",
            "school":{"SchoolGroupe":"TrowMet", "SchoolName":"VeronM"}},
            "id":"145",
            "Mother":{"MotherName":"Helen","MotherAge":"46"},"NGlobalNote":2,
            "Father":{"FatherName":"Peter","FatherAge":"51"},
             "Study":[{
            "Teacher":["MrCrock","MrDaniel"],
           "Field":{"Master1":["Marketing", "Politics", "Philosophy"], 
           "Master2":["Economics", "Management"], "ExamCode": "1256"}
             }],
             "season":["summer","spring"]}
```

I need to parse this file, in order to extract only some key-values from every json, to obtain the dataframe that should look like:

```
Groupe       Id   MotherName   FatherName    Master2
Advanced    56   Laure         James        Economics, Management
Middle      11   Ann           Nicolas      Web-development
Advanced    6    Helen         Franc        Literature, English Language
```

I use [method proposed me in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35645790/5960260) `.get` but it doesn't work with nested json, so for instance if I try:

```
def extract_data(data):
    """ convert 1 json dict to records for import"""
    dummy = {}
    jfile = json.loads(data.strip())
    return (
    jfile.get('Study', dummy).get('Field', np.nan).get('Master1',np.nan),
    jfile.get('location', dummy).get('groupe', np.nan))
```

for this line `jfile.get('Study', dummy).get('Field', np.nan).get('Master1', np.nan)`  it throws me an error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

obviously it happens because the value of `"Study"` is not a dictionary, neither list, but a valid json!  how can I deal with this problem? Does exist a method that works like .get, but for json? I guess there is another option : decode this json and then parse it with `.get`, but the problem that it is in the core of another json, so I have no clue how to decode it!

Comment: Instead of chaining the last call to `get` you can check if what you get under the key `Master1` is a list and then get all list values or alternatively a single value, if the value of `Master1` is not a list

Comment: By the way could you correct the `get('Master1','np.nan)` to `get('Master1',np.nan)` in your post?

Comment: @YannisP. could you be more precise about how I can implement it, please? Peace of code, method?

Comment: I hope you were able to sort this out with Forge's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Data` is a valid [`JSON`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) formatted string. `JSON` contains four basic elements:

- **Object**: defined with curly braces `{}`
- **Array**: defined with braces `[]`
- **Value**: can be a *string*, a *number*, an *object*, an *array*, or the *literals true*, *false* or *null*
- **String**: defined by double quotes and contain `Unicode` characters or common `backslash escapes`

Using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) will convert the `string` into a python `object` recursively. It means that every inner `JSON` element will be represented as a python `object`.

Therefore:
`jfile.get('Study')` ---> `python list`

To retrieve `Field` you should iterate over the study list:

```
file = json.loads(data.strip())
study_list = jfile.get('Study', [])  # don't set default value with different type 
for item in study_list:
  print item.get('Field')
```

Comment: ow, thank you! I get it, but in this case, how can I extract the value from this list?

Comment: Oh it is like `l=jfile.get.get('Study', dummy)` and then `l[0]` gives you the first element or you can write an iteration. See examples here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: @Forge excellent explanation and solution! thank you very much!